# How can I handle the Class Cast Exception using switch case?

Tags: java, exception

Where to place try catch in the below program to handle Class Cast Exception?

```
Class Animal { }
Class Dog extends Animal { }
Class Cat extends Animal { }
Class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Main method started");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the key value");
        int key = sc.nextInt();
        Animal a = null;
        switch (key) {
            case 1 : a = new Cat(); break;
            case 2 : a = new Dog(); break;
            default : System.out.println("invalid choice");
            return;
        }
        Dog d = (Dog)a;
        System.out.println("main method ended");
    }
}
```

The downcasting is not done for Cat class , so when enter the key value as 1, it will throw Class cast Exception. How to handle it by using try catch ? where to insert the try catch so that it gets handled?

Comment: Can you please indent the code properly using a java code beautifier?

Comment: Why do you want to handle exception? With checking its type using `instanceof` you can prevent it. But if you must use try-catch then can you explain what problems are you facing when you use it normally (we use try to wrap section which can throw exception; catch to provide way of handling it)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes as mentioned by @Pshemo; you should use instanceof operator to check if its instance of Dog and initialise it accordingly

```
Dog d=null;
if(a instanceof Dog)
  d=(Dog)a;
System.out.println(d);
```

Ideally you should not need to downcast. unless you have to invoke specialized method implemented by your subclass. Otherwise the interface/parent class method should be used.

```
example : a.eat() // eat will be present in animal and will be implemented differently in each sub-class dog and cat.
```

but if you need to bark for example; then you may need to sub-cast, but doing it in safe way using instanceof

```
if (a instanceof Dog) ((Dog)a).bark();
else syso("Animal cannot bark");
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare the two varibales of each type and initialize in the case statement.

```
public class MainRunner {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            System.out.println("Main method started");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter the key value");
            int key = sc.nextInt();
            Animal a = null;
            Dog d=null;
            Cat c=null;
            switch (key) {
                case 1 : a = new Cat();
                c=(Cat)a;
                break;
                case 2 : a = new Dog();
                d=(Dog)a;
                break;
                default : System.out.println("invalid choice");
                return;
            }
             if(d!=null){/*  to do */}
             if(c!=null){/*  to do */}
            System.out.println("main method ended");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to catch exception, just use `instanceof` method, before cast.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Main method started");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the key value");
        int key = sc.nextInt();
        Animal a = null;
        switch (key){
            case 1 : a = new Cat(); break;
            case 2 : a = new Dog(); break;
            default : System.out.println("invalid choice");
            return;
        }
        Dog d;
        Cat c;
        if(a!= null && a instanceof Dog)
            d =(Dog)a;
        else if(a!= null && a instanceof Cat)
            c = (Cat)c;

        System.out.println("main method ended");
    }
```

Comment: While I agree with `instanceof`, how using it this way will help OP? Now scope of `Dog d` is limited only to that one line in which it was declared.

Comment: @Pshemo you're right, I just assumed that this is a sample code to show `instanceof` usage not a real application. edited the code a little, but it's still not a clean code :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of any try catch. you can avoid `ClassCastException` by just using `instanceof` operator like as below -

```
Class Animal { }
Class Dog extends Animal { }
Class Cat extends Animal { }
Class MainRunner {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Main method started");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the key value");
        int key = sc.nextInt();
        Animal a = null;
        switch (key) {
        case 1 : a = new Cat(); break;
        case 2 : a = new Dog(); break;
        default : System.out.println("invalid choice");
        return;
        }
        /* 
         * as per your logic of default block, for invalid choice control is getting 
         * returned back from default block only and if control comes here it means 
         * `a` will not have null value, so skipping null check
         * */
        if(a instanceof Dog){
            Dog d = (Dog)a;
            }
        else{
            Cat c = (Cat)a;
            }
        System.out.println("main method ended");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

People here are giving you solutions (or as I would better call them - 'hacks') to fix this problem of yours, when the solution is to avoid this kind of a situation at all.

The whole point of having the `Animal` class is to avoid downcasting later. Your switch does basically what a [Factory Pattern (checkout Step 3)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) does, this pattern is widely used in libraries and frameworks, not only in Java. The fact that you don't know what comes out of the factory is actually a good thing, it gives you and the person who delivers the actual implementations (it doesn't have to be you) a lot of flexibility.

If you want, let's say, downcast to `Dog`, because you need to call the `bark` method - don't, create `makeSound` method in `Animal` class and then override/implement it accordingly in the `Dog` class.